# Audio File PlaylistParsingException

Tags: jmeter, video-streaming, performance-testing, load-testing, audio-streaming

I have the following Exception while Testing an audio File (.m4a) on Jmeter:

- com.blazemeter.jmeter.videostreaming.core.exception.PlaylistParsingException: Error parsing contents from https://iceportal.de/aod-audiobooks/a617f70d2629b0064ebdef2620c55ad2/5eba8d0f/37-000000000006/001_italienisch_basis_lektion_01.m4a
  at com.blazemeter.jmeter.videostreaming.hls.Playlist.fromUriAndBody(Playlist.java:56) ~[jmeter-bzm-hls-3.0.1.jar:?]
- Caused by: com.blazemeter.jmeter.videostreaming.core.exception.PlaylistParsingException: Error parsing contents from https://iceportal.de/aod-audiobooks/a617f70d2629b0064ebdef2620c55ad2/5eba8d0f/37-000000000006/001_italienisch_basis_lektion_01.m4a: No playlist tags found
  at com.blazemeter.jmeter.videostreaming.hls.Playlist.fromUriAndBody(Playlist.java:52) ~[jmeter-bzm-hls-3.0.1.jar:?]

here is my enviroment:

- Jmeter Version:5.2.1
- HLS Pluging 3.0 Version
- Java Version: OpenJDK 1.8 (64 Bit)
- The URL: https://iceportal.de/aod-audiobooks/a617f70d2629b0064ebdef2620c55ad2/5eba8d0f/37-000000000006/001_italienisch_basis_lektion_01.m4a

Answer (score 1):

You're using wrong sampler, M4A is not a video-streaming playlist, it's a normal [MPEG-4 file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MPEG-4_Part_14#.MP4_versus_.M4A), it is being delivered immediately after the request and is played by your operating system media player.

If you need to simulate concurrent access to MPEG4 files just use normal [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler configured like:

[image]

Don't forget to add a [Constant Timer](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/comprehensive-guide-using-jmeter-timers/) and configure think time more or less equal to the duration of your media file to mimic a real user watching the video or listening to the audio

Comment: @Dimiri-----but according to the HLS 3.0.1 documentation, with HLS we can test video and audio streaming segment too, hence I'm not sure if test it with the HTTP Request sampler a load simulation on the audio streaming applications is achieved or not...